# SVM implementation problem with CVXPY: Persistent errors with RBF kernel and linear kernel

Tags: python, svm, libsvm, cvxpy

I'm working on an SVM (Support Vector Machine) implementation using CVXPY in Python. Unfortunately, I'm having persistent problems with both the RBF kernel and the linear kernel.

I define the optimization problem with the necessary variables and constraints, but I get incompatible dimension errors when executing the optimization function.

Here's an excerpt from the code where the problem seems to occur, specifically in the constraint definition:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmW4n.png)

error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRLYF.png)

code :

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class SVM:
    def __init__(self, kernel='linear', C=None):
      self.kernel = kernel
      self.C = C
      self.alpha = None
      self.b = None
      self.X_train = None
      self.y_train = None

    def _linear_kernel(self, x1, x2):
        return np.dot(x1, x2)

    def _rbf_kernel(self, x1, x2, gamma=0.1):
        return np.exp(-gamma * np.sum((x1 - x2)**2))

    def fit(self, X, y):
    
    # Avant la définition des variables et des contraintes
        print("Dimensions de X avant optimisation :", X.shape)
        print("Dimensions de y avant optimisation :", y.shape)

    
    
        self.X_train = X
        self.y_train = y
        m,n  = X.shape

    # Variables
        alpha = cp.Variable(n)
        xi = cp.Variable(m)
        b = cp.Variable()
    # Après la définition des variables
        print("Dimensions de alpha après définition :", alpha.shape)

    # Constraints
        constraints = [0 <= alpha, alpha <= self.C, xi >= 0, cp.sum(cp.multiply(y, cp.matmul(X, alpha) + b)) >= 1 - xi]


    # Après la définition des contraintes
        print("Dimensions de X @ alpha après contraintes :", (X @ alpha).shape)

    # Objective function
        obj = cp.Minimize(0.5 * cp.norm(alpha)**2 + self.C * cp.sum(xi))

    # Problem definition
        prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)

    # Solve the problem
        prob.solve()

    # Store the results
        self.alpha = alpha.value
        self.b = b.value

    def predict(self, X):
        decision_function = X @ self.X_train.T @ self.alpha + self.b
        return np.sign(decision_function)

def plot_decision_boundary(self, X, y):
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired, edgecolors='k', marker='o')

    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1

    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.1),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.1))

    Z = self.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

    plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, alpha=0.3, levels=[-1, 0, 1], cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
    plt.xlabel('Feature 1')
    plt.ylabel('Feature 2')
    plt.title(f'Decision Boundary for {self.kernel.capitalize()} SVM')
    plt.show()
    # mes données d'entraînement
    X_train = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]])
    y_train = np.array([-1, -1, 1, 1])


    # Exemple d'utilisation :
    # Création d'une instance de la classe SVM avec un kernel RBF et C=1
   svm_rbf = SVM(kernel='linear', C=0.025)
   # Entraînement sur un jeu de données X_train, y_train
   svm_rbf.fit(X_train, y_train)
   # Affichage de la frontière de décision
   svm_rbf.plot_decision_boundary(X_train, y_train)
```

error predict :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfrLH.png)

I'm going through the necessary checks for the dimensions of my training data (X: (4, 2), y: (4,)), and I've also checked that the dimensions of my variables (alpha) are correctly defined.

I'm open to any suggestions or corrections to solve these implementation problems, whether with the RBF kernel or the linear kernel.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your arguments of ``cp.matmul`` don't match dimensions. ``alpha`` should have length ``n``, not ``m``.

Comment: even doing this I have a error again , the error is shown in the image above

Comment: Reproducible code sample which can be copy-pasted and run, please.

Comment: I put the code above

Comment: It does not run (missing indentation) and there is no input data so this is not what we can call a reproducible example demonstrating the issue. I can only guess from the error you posted that you have two objects of incompatible dimensions (m,1) and (m) which you are trying to add or pointwise multiply.

Comment: I've modified the code above and added the tests and I can't see how to correct the error. I've tried changing the dimensions and I still get this error.

Comment: You just peel the problematic expression like an onion and check dimensions from the inside, and then you find that ``y`` and ``A@x+b`` are incompatible. The most natural solution is to declare ``alpha = cp.Variable(n)`` instead what you have now.

Comment: ok, I did what you asked and it worked thanks for your help but I have another problem with the predict method, still a problem with the dimensions. it tells me "The dimension of the product self.X_train.T , self.alpha and X is not compatible. "I've tried adjusting the dimensions but it doesn't work. I've put a capture of the error above.